# How should I detect a mob that no longer has a passenger?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

On Minecraft 1.12, I'm making a thing for a boss fight, and it has baby zombies riding chickens. You can kill the zombies and they will die but the chicken won't. How should I detect the chicken no longer having a passenger?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you can't just test for an empty list of passengers, because the game removes the `Passengers` tag when the zombie is killed instead of just emptying it.
But you can detect all chickens and you can detect all chickens **with** passengers, so you can do something like this:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=chicken] add noPassenger
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=chicken] remove noPassenger {Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:zombie"}]}
```

This first adds the tag `noPassenger` to all chickens and then removes it from every chicken that is ridden by a zombie. You can later select all tagged chickens with `@e[tag=noPassenger]`.

Comment: More generally, you can do `{Passengers:[{}]}` to detect whether an entity has *any* passengers, not just zombies.

Comment: Interesting, didn't try that.